# Probability of $j$ or more out of $k$ numbers higher than mine

Tags: probability

All numbers are drawn out of a uniform distribution between $0$ and $x_{max}$. If we have a game where me, and another $k$ players pick a number at random. What is the probability that there are $j$ or more players with a higher number than mine?

The way I am thinking about it is:

$P\{ j$ player get higher than me $\} = \int_{0}^{x_{max}} \frac{1}{x_{max}} P\{\ge j \ higher \ than \ me \ | I \ get \ x\} dx$

where:

$P\{ j$ player get higher than me | I get $x\} = \sum_{z=j}^{k} {k \choose z} (1-\frac{x}{x_{max}})^{z}\frac{x}{x_{max}}^{k-z}$

Is this correct? In that case how can the previous integral be solved? I feel there has to be a simple expression for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral turns out to be very simple:
$$P[\mathrm{at\ least\ }j \mathrm{\ players\ out\ of\ } k \mathrm{\ get\ higher\ number\ than\ me}]=1-\frac{j}{k+1}$$

Put differently, probability that *exactly* $j$ players will have higher number is equal to $\frac{1}{k+1}$ (for all $j$).

Comment: Thanks! Now that I see the answer, I guess a way to think about it is saying that the probability of exactly $j$ players having a higher number, is the probability of me being in position $j+1$ in an ordered list. Given the symmetry of the problem we should all have the same probability of being in that position, hence the $\frac{1}{k+1}$.